# How to get token and save it for later so no need to login every time?

Tags: javascript, azure, oauth, azure-mobile-services

How to get the Oauth token in the following code?

```
var mobileServiceClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient('https://...azurewebsites.net');
mobileService.login("facebook", $scope.token).done(function (results) {
    $scope.token = result.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken;
    //??? how to get the first/renewed token?
}
```

It got the following error when opening the login page again.

```
Error: 'token' is expected to be a value of type object, not string.
    at Object.c.createError (azure-mobile-apps-client.min.js:17)
    at azure-mobile-apps-client.min.js:17
    at new b (azure-mobile-apps-client.min.js:17)
    at d.login (azure-mobile-apps-client.min.js:17)
    at ChildScope.$scope.signWithFackBook (controllers.js:10)
    at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:27643), :4:239)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65429
    at ChildScope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at ChildScope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30500)
    at HTMLButtonElement. (ionic.bundle.js:65428)
```

BTW, I want the page to redirect to the main page if the token is valid.

```
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state) {

    if ($scope.token ....is good...) // Need to test if the token is good
    { 
        $state.go('tab.events'); 
    }

    $scope.signWithFackBook = function () {
      $rootScope.client.login('facebook', $scope.token).done(function (result) {
        $scope.token = result.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken;
        $state.go('tab.events');
      }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert('Failed to login!');
      });
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the API documentation](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/MobileServiceClient.html#login), the optional parameter `token` within `login()` function needs to be provided as specific object instead of string with existing OAuth token. That raises your issue.

> Error: 'token' is expected to be a value of type object, not string.

Actually, you can use the following: `$rootScope.client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken` to get authenticated token.

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state) {

  if ($rootScope.client.currentUser && $rootScope.client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken) {
    $state.go('tab.events'); 
  }

  $scope.signWithFackBook = function () {
    $rootScope.client.login('facebook').done(function (result) {
      $state.go('tab.events');
    }, function (error) {
      console.error(error);
      alert('Failed to login!');
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: I' will actually use it in Cordova/ionic, should I save  $rootScope.client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken in  local storage? Or will it be persistent automatically?

Comment: And what if the token expired?

Comment: Read my "30 days of Azure Mobile" at https://shellmonger.com - it covers refresh tokens.  Yes, you can persist the token in local storage, but it's likely to be expired, so ensure you have a refresh token ready to go and refresh it as soon as your app restarts.

Comment: @aaronChen, I tried it in Chrome after `ionic server` and `$rootScope.client.currentUser` is always null.

Comment: @AdrianHall Thanks. I will read the page https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/13/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-7-refresh-tokens/ to understand how to persist and refresh the token. Basically, like a lot of apps, I want to once the users logged in the app using facebook on the phone, the don't need to login the app again. Is the article covered this function?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9, Based on [source code of JavaScript client SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/blob/master/sdk/src/MobileServiceLogin.js#L297), it will set the current user on the client when the login completed. So have you tried it in Android emulator?

Comment: @AaronChen-MSFT, I didn't try it in the emulator. However, I tried `.done(function (result) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', result.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
        localStorage.setItem('token2', $rootScope.client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken);` and both `token` and `token2` were set to the same value. I think I will use localStorage and I'm trying to do refreshing token now.